# How to parse a list quickly using a C# Method that only takes an item?

Tags: c#

I am learning C# myself and I wonder if C# method can quickly parse a list of values just like Python does as below:

```py
def myMethod(somevalue):
    return somevalue * 2

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = [myMethod(i) for i in x]
```

Currently I am trying to make a class that has a method that takes in a double.
But what if x is a list?

```
  class myClass
  {
    public double somevalue;
    public myClass(double someValue)
    {
      somevalue = someValue;
    }
    
    public double myMethod()
    {
      return somevalue * 2;
    }
  }

myClass output = new myClass(x);
A = output.myMethod();
```

My question is, can C# create very concise codes that makes the Method takes in the list, loop through the list and gives out a list of results?

Comment: Please name your (public) fields and methods using PascalCase. Use camelCase for local variables, and consider _camelCase for private fields. Avoid using case alone to discriminate; it's a recipe for bugs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a python expert but this:

```
def myMethod(somevalue):
    return somevalue * 2

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = [myMethod(i) for i in x]
```

Looks like it would be this in C#:

```
//either:
double TimesTwo(double d) => d * 2;          //a method declaration that is "expression bodied" style

//or:
double TimesTwo(double d) { return d * 2; }  //a method declaration that is "normal" style


void SomeOtherMethod(){                      //these statements can't just be floating around in a namespace like the method declarations above, they have to be inside some other method

    var x = new[] {1d,2,3,4,5};              //the first element is a double (1d), the others will be promoted from int to double without needing an explicit cast, the whole array x is a double[]
    var a = x.Select(TimesTwo).ToArray();

}
```

You can skip creating a separate method for the `* 2` operation (the method above is called TimesTwo) and just put the logic of what you want inline:

```
    var x = new[] { 1d,2,3,4,5 };
    var a = x.Select(p => p * 2).ToArray();
```

The `p => p * 2` is something like an "inline method" - we refer to them as lambdas; the input argument is called `p` and its type is inferred from the type of the collection that `.Select` is called on. In this case a `double` is inferred, because `x` is a `double` array

The `return` keyword is not specified in a single line lambda (which we refer to as an *expression bodied* something); the single line of code after the `=>` (in both `p => ...` and `TimesTwo(int i) => ...`) is a statement that resolves to a value, and that value is implicitly returned. In this case the statement `p => p * 2` multiplies input `p` by 2 and the result is returned automatically.

The result of the `.Select` method is an enumerable (specifically of type `IEnumerable<double>`, and the `ToArray()` method will enumerate it and turn it into an array. It is the calling of ToArray that causes `p*2` to be invoked on every member, and ToArray collects all the results and outputs an array

All this code comes from extension methods in the `System.Linq` namespace, so your code needs `using System.Linq;` at the top

---

One important point, that may well bite at some time in the future; the code in the lambda within the Select is not performed *if the enumerable output by the Select is not actually enumerated*. If you had:

```
var enumerableThing = oneThousandThings.Select(p => SomeOperationThatTakesOneSecond(p));
```

It would execute near instantly; nothing in that line of code enumerates the resulting enumerable, no memory is allocated for a new array, no looping over collections of anything occurs, the operation that takes 1 second is not even called once let alone a thousand times.

If you later did something that actually enumerated the result, *then* the operation would take a thousand seconds:

```
var arr = enumerableThing.ToArray() //takes 1000s


foreach(var x in enumerableThing)  //would take 1000s to finish looping
  ...


int i = 500;                       
foreach(var x in enumerableThing){ //would take 500s, the enumeration quitting early after being half done
  i--;
  if(i == 0) break;
}
```

This enumerating could be done hours or days later; it's called deferred execution and is worth looking into further if you're not familiar with it

Comment: I am constantly amazed how helpful the people on stackoverflow are!
I really learnt a lot from reading your explanation!!!

Answer (score 3):

You would use `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where()` to filter the List

```
var filtered = x.Where(y => myMethod(y)).ToList();
```

or `Select` to convert the list

```
var converted = x.Select(y => myMethod(y)).ToList();
```